# Async Code Running out of order randomly missing variable decelerations

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I keep having this code error
do to the fact that the createChannel section tries to run before 'newChannelRole' is defined
I know this is due to some of the nature of async function but i cant seem to figure out the correct way to ensure things happen in order. Especially because what parts of my code it happens in seem to be random

```
    async run(msg,args){
        //get our guilds Information
        let guildID = msg.guild.id;
        let locationDataKey = guildID+"_mapData";

        //Our Guild Settings
        let settingMapKey = guildID+"_setting";
        let settings = settingsMap.get(settingMapKey);

        //load up our location Data Array
        let locationDataArray = data.get(locationDataKey);

        //make the new channel
        let formatedNameDashes = args.name.replace(/ /g,"-");
        let formatedNameSpace  = args.name.replace(/-/g," ")

        //make a role for the channel
        let newChannelRole;
        msg.guild.createRole({
            name:formatedNameSpace
        }).then( x => {
            newChannelRole = x;
        });

        //Make the Channel and set the new permissions
        //Everyone has none, NPCs and the unique channel role can see it/type/read history
        msg.guild.createChannel(formatedNameDashes,{
            type:'text',
            permissionOverwrites:[
                {
                    id:msg.guild.defaultRole,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL','SEND_MESSAGES','READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
                },
                {
                    id:settings.npcRoleID,
                    allow:['VIEW_CHANNEL','SEND_MESSAGES','READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
                },
                {
                    id:newChannelRole.id,
                    allow:['VIEW_CHANNEL','SEND_MESSAGES','READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']

                }
            ]
        }).then( channel => {
            //move it into the category
            let rpCategory = msg.guild.channels.get(settings.rpCategoryID)
            channel.setParent(rpCategory);

            //push the information into the locationDataArray
            mapDataArray.push({
                name:formatedNameSpace,
                channelName:channel.name,
                connections:[],
                channelID:channel.id
            });

            //save the locationDataArray
            data.set(locationDataKey,locationDataKey);     
        });   
    }
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript!!

Comment: Why use `.then` in an `async` function?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the code following your call to `then` doesn't wait for the promise that `then` is connected to to settle. To make it wait, you'd have to put it all *in* the `then` handler after the `newChannelRole = x;` line.

But since you're using an `async` function, don't use `.then`, use `await`. See the `***` comments:

```
async run(msg,args){
    //get our guilds Information
    let guildID = msg.guild.id;
    let locationDataKey = guildID+"_mapData";

    //Our Guild Settings
    let settingMapKey = guildID+"_setting";
    let settings = settingsMap.get(settingMapKey);

    //load up our location Data Array
    let locationDataArray = data.get(locationDataKey);

    //make the new channel
    let formatedNameDashes = args.name.replace(/ /g,"-");
    let formatedNameSpace  = args.name.replace(/-/g," ")

    //make a role for the channel
    let newChannelRole = await msg.guild.createRole({                        // ***
        name:formatedNameSpace
    });

    //Make the Channel and set the new permissions
    //Everyone has none, NPCs and the unique channel role can see it/type/read history
    const channel = await msg.guild.createChannel(formatedNameDashes,{       // ***
        type:'text',
        permissionOverwrites:[
            {
                id:msg.guild.defaultRole,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL','SEND_MESSAGES','READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
            },
            {
                id:settings.npcRoleID,
                allow:['VIEW_CHANNEL','SEND_MESSAGES','READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']
            },
            {
                id:newChannelRole.id,
                allow:['VIEW_CHANNEL','SEND_MESSAGES','READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY']

            }
        ]
    });

    //move it into the category
    let rpCategory = msg.guild.channels.get(settings.rpCategoryID)
    channel.setParent(rpCategory);

    //push the information into the locationDataArray
    mapDataArray.push({
        name:formatedNameSpace,
        channelName:channel.name,
        connections:[],
        channelID:channel.id
    });

    //save the locationDataArray
    data.set(locationDataKey,locationDataKey);     
}
```

---

Note that whatever calls `run` needs to handle the fact that `run` returns a promise (because **all** `async` functions return promises). In particular it's important that whatever calls it handles promise rejection (or passes the promise on to something that will).

Answer (score 2):

Change this bit:

```
msg.guild.createRole({
        name:formatedNameSpace
    }).then( x => {
        newChannelRole = x;
    });
```

to this:

```
newChannelRole = await msg.guild.createRole({
        name:formatedNameSpace
    })
```

Comment: There's another one further on that needs to be changed too, so the `async` function correctly rejects its promise if that second bit fails.

Comment: true, i noticed that but chose to focus on his specific problem. Should absolutely modify his code to use `await` on all promises.

Comment: Oh! That makes a ton of sense. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When Using an async function try the implementation with await

```js
function sleep(ms) {
                                        
                    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
                  }
function SecondCall()
{
console.log('I got called in order');
}
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
   console.log(result);
   await sleep(1000);
 SecondCall();


  // expected output: 'resolved'
}

asyncCall();
```